# How to prevent all programs from using AlwaysOnTop?

Tags: windows-10

I don't know how many programs I've used who think they're the most important things in the world and set themselves to AlwaysOnTop. If I open the task manager, even though it's the active window, it's below these programs because they've set themselves to AlwaysOnTop. This is also a problem when the programs hide my AHK debug prompts.

Usually commonly-used programs will have some users that found ways to disable these sorts of things, but not all of the programs I'm using are common. Windows has built-in AlwaysOnTop functionality, and I assume that's what these programs are using, so I'd like a global way to prevent all programs from using that. While using my computer, in 100% of the case the active window should be on top -- I don't want any other programs trying to force their way in front of the active window. Is there any way to accomplish this at a global level?

Comment: Always On Top is indeed something you can set through the windows API, but to my knowledge there is no way to disable this. Then again, I'm not aware of many programs having this functionality, so I'd look into disabling them from the program. Alternatively, it might be that a third party program is used to set windows always on top. There are programs that can set a window on top and specify a certain criteria. I bet such program could be used to do the opposite as well. But who knows, maybe someone here knows a regkey that does just this... For that reason, this is a comment, not an answer.

Comment: As a Suggestion I would check out this [Link](http://www.abstractpath.com/powermenu/) as it lets you set the priorities of windows.